# How do I extract the crab claw meat clinging to, and covered by, the shells?

Tags: crab

I defrosted these Snow Crab claws, but the meat still clings to the shell. I can't yank all the claw meat out of the shell  intact and in one go, because the meat keeps splitting and sundering at the blue line! How do I extract the meat still fastened inside the shell?

I bought a pair of chopsticks. But each claw takes 5 minutes to pluck out remaining meat with ONE chopstick! This is too unproductive!

[image]

Comment: you could use a small spoon ?

Comment: @Max Are there spoons small enough to do this? I don't have any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cut the shell lengthwise (best with a pair of kitchen scissors), open it up, and pull or scrape the meat out.